# WinForms .NET 2.0: How to paint the proper sized icon?

Tags: winforms, graphics, windows-vista

i have an ico file that contains a 48x48 and a 256x256 Vista PNG version (as well as the 32x32 and 16x16 versions). i want to draw the icon using the appropriate internal size version.

i've tried:

```
Icon ico = Properties.Resources.TestIcon;
e.Graphics.DrawIcon(ico, new Rectangle(0, 0, 48, 48));
e.Graphics.DrawIcon(ico, new Rectangle(48, 0, 256, 256));
```

But they draw the 32x32 version blown up to 48x48 and 256x256 respectively.

i've tried:

```
Icon ico = Properties.Resources.TestIcon;
e.Graphics.DrawIconUnstretched(ico, new Rectangle(0, 0, 48, 48));
e.Graphics.DrawIconUnstretched(ico, new Rectangle(48 0, 256, 256));
```

But those draw the 32x32 version unstretched.

i've tried:

```
Icon ico = Properties.Resources.TestIcon;
e.Graphics.DrawImage(ico.ToBitmap(), new Rectangle(0, 0, 48, 48));
e.Graphics.DrawImage(ico.ToBitmap(), new Rectangle(48, 0, 256, 256));
```

But those draw a stretched version of the 32x32 icon.

How do i make the icon draw itself using the appropriate size?

Additionally, i want to draw using the 16x16 version. i've tried:

```
Icon ico = Properties.Resources.TestIcon;
e.Graphics.DrawIcon(ico, new Rectangle(0, 0, 16, 16));
e.Graphics.DrawIconUnstretched(ico, new Rectangle(24, 0, 16, 16));
e.Graphics.DrawImage(ico.ToBitmap(), new Rectangle(48, 0, 16, 16));
```

But all those use the 32x32 version scaled down, except for the `Unstretched` call, which crops it to 16x16.

How do i make the icon draw itself using the appropriate size?

---

Following schnaader's suggestion of constructing a copy of the icon with the size you need doesn't work for 256x256 size. i.e. the following does not work (it uses a scaled version of the 48x48 icon):

```
e.Graphics.DrawIcon(
        new Icon(ico, new Size(256, 256)), 
        new Rectangle(0, 0, 256, 256));
```

While the following two do work:

```
e.Graphics.DrawIcon(
        new Icon(ico, new Size(16, 16)), 
        new Rectangle(0, 0, 16, 16));

e.Graphics.DrawIcon(
        new Icon(ico, new Size(48, 48)), 
        new Rectangle(0, 0, 48, 48));
```

Comment: You commented that both suggested solutions didn't work for you. But some time has passed. Did you ever manage to display the proper icon sizes? I am in a similar situation now so I'm interested.

Answer (score 1):

Today, I made a very nice function for **extracting the 256x256 Bitmaps from Vista icons**.

I use it to display the large icon ( **256x256** ) as a Bitmap in "About" box. For example, this code gets Vista icon as PNG image, and displays it in a 256x256 PictureBox:

```
picboxAppLogo.Image = ExtractVistaIcon(Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(myIcon));
```

This function takes Icon object as a parameter. So, you can use it with any icons - **from resources**, from files, from streams, and so on. (Read below about extracting EXE icon).

It runs on **any OS**, because it does **not** use any Win32 API, it is **100% managed code** :-)

```
// Based on: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/IconExtractor.aspx
// And a hint from: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/IconLib.aspx

Bitmap ExtractVistaIcon(Icon icoIcon)
{
    Bitmap bmpPngExtracted = null;
    try
    {
        byte[] srcBuf = null;
        using (System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
            { icoIcon.Save(stream); srcBuf = stream.ToArray(); }
        const int SizeICONDIR = 6;
        const int SizeICONDIRENTRY = 16;
        int iCount = BitConverter.ToInt16(srcBuf, 4);
        for (int iIndex=0; iIndex<iCount; iIndex++)
        {
            int iWidth  = srcBuf[SizeICONDIR + SizeICONDIRENTRY * iIndex];
            int iHeight = srcBuf[SizeICONDIR + SizeICONDIRENTRY * iIndex + 1];
            int iBitCount   = BitConverter.ToInt16(srcBuf, SizeICONDIR + SizeICONDIRENTRY * iIndex + 6);
            if (iWidth == 0 && iHeight == 0 && iBitCount == 32)
            {
                int iImageSize   = BitConverter.ToInt32(srcBuf, SizeICONDIR + SizeICONDIRENTRY * iIndex + 8);
                int iImageOffset = BitConverter.ToInt32(srcBuf, SizeICONDIR + SizeICONDIRENTRY * iIndex + 12);
                System.IO.MemoryStream destStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
                System.IO.BinaryWriter writer = new System.IO.BinaryWriter(destStream);
                writer.Write(srcBuf, iImageOffset, iImageSize);
                destStream.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
                bmpPngExtracted = new Bitmap(destStream); // This is PNG! :)
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    catch { return null; }
    return bmpPngExtracted;
}
```

**IMPORTANT!** If you want to load this icon directly from EXE file, then you **CAN'T** use *Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(Application.ExecutablePath)* as a parameter, because .NET function ExtractAssociatedIcon() is so stupid, it extracts ONLY 32x32 icon!

Instead, you better use the whole **IconExtractor** class, created by Tsuda Kageyu (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/IconExtractor.aspx). You can slightly simplify this class, to make it smaller. Use **IconExtractor** this way:

```
// Getting FILL icon set from EXE, and extracting 256x256 version for logo...
using (TKageyu.Utils.IconExtractor IconEx = new TKageyu.Utils.IconExtractor(Application.ExecutablePath))
{
    Icon icoAppIcon = IconEx.GetIcon(0); // Because standard System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon() returns ONLY 32x32.
    picboxAppLogo.Image = ExtractVistaIcon(icoAppIcon);
}
```

Note: I'm still using my ExtractVistaIcon() function here, because I don't like how **IconExtractor** handles this job - first, it extracts all icon formats by using IconExtractor.SplitIcon(icoAppIcon), and then you have to know the exact 256x256 icon index to get the desired vista-icon. So, using my ExtractVistaIcon() here is much faster and simplier way :)