# How to set HICON on a window (.ICO with multiple sizes)?

Tags: windows, winapi, icons

I would like to define the application icon of a Win32 window, e.g. through a call to `SetClassLong` with `GCL_HICON` and passing in a handle to an icon (see [SetClassLong Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633588(VS.85).aspx) on MSDN).

This works great, but I have not figured out how I should load an icon (from an ICO file) in order to keep all available sizes (e.g. 16x16, 32x32, 48x48 and full size PNG icon). When I load the icon file through `LoadImage` into memory to get the `HICON`, I have to specify which size I want (see my [reply to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287041/winforms-net-2-0-how-to-draw-a-png-icon/1061822#1061822)).

My ICO file contains a small sized image which should be used as the window icon (top left corner of the title bar) and has been designed to be very crisp, but also larger variants which should show up in the Alt-Tab dialog, but...

1. Loading the 16x16 icon shows the proper icon in the title bar, but - of course - an ugly stretched version of it when I Alt-Tab. And the one showing up in the task bar is not very pretty either.
2. Loading the 48x48 icon shows a nice icon when I Alt-Tab, but the icon which shows up in the title bar is blurry, since it is a scaled down version of the 48x48 icon.

Is there any means of telling Windows that my Windows has a multi-sized icon? Is there some obvious API which I have missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GCL_HICON sets the "big" icon, GCL_HICONSM sets the small icon (Sizes are normally 32x32 and 16x16, but you should use GetSystemMetrics with SM_CXICON and SM_CXSMICON to find the actual size (For the large icon, you can also just pass LR_DEFAULTSIZE to LoadImage with 0 size))

Comment: Currently, I cannot get `SetClassLong` to work as expected on my WinForms application. The default WinForms icon wins; and when I Alt-Tab, I get a short glimpse of my icon, but then the default WinForms icon is painted on top of mine. Strange. If I cannot figure this out by myself, I'll post another question on stack overflow.

Comment: The other question is here, in case you wonder: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266479

Answer (score 6):

an .ICO file has multiple images in it.  but a HICON is only *one* of those images.  if you use LR_DEFAULTSIZE, then there may be some magical behavior that preserves a link to the .ico file and uses the appropriate image from it, but I doubt it.

If this doesn't do it, then nothing will.

```
HICON hicon = LoadImage(NULL, "filename.ico", IMAGE_ICON, 
                        0, 0, LR_DEFAULTSIZE | LR_LOADFROMFILE);
```

A little background.

When a .ico file is included in a application's resources, the file is cracked open and each image from the file becomes a *separate* resource.  The file header is modified and it becomes the ICON resource.  So when LoadIcon/LoadImage is passed the resource id of an ICON resource, it's really being passed a directory of other resources.  It chooses the image that fits the request *at that point in time* and turns it into an HICON.  The function that actually does this is called [LookupIconIdFromDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648073(VS.85).aspx)

This is why when you [GetIconInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648070(VS.85).aspx) for an HICON, you get back only a single ICONINFO structure.

```
typedef struct _ICONINFO {
    BOOL fIcon;
    DWORD xHotspot;
    DWORD yHotspot;
    HBITMAP hbmMask;
    HBITMAP hbmColor;
} ICONINFO;
```

Comment: For LR_DEFAULTSIZE MSDN says: "If the resource contains multiple images, the function uses the size of the first image"

Comment: @Anders: yes. but the .NET ICON appears to keep track of the .ico source and when you ask it to make a new icon from the old one, it will reach back into the source rather than just stretching.  I think this _might_ also be true for unmanaged icons, but I have no definitive knowledge either way.

Comment: Thank you for your ideas and explanations. LR_DEFAULTSIZE does not, however, do the magical behaviour we were dreaming of. I guess that I will have to use GCL_HICON and GCL_HICONSM; I'll report back in by commenting Anders' reply.

Comment: Hi @PierreArnaud can you share your findings on your last comment please. I have a ico container and am trying to use `SetClassLongPtr` to apply the right size to big and small.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266479/setclasslonghwnd-gcl-hicon-hicon-cannot-replace-winforms-form-icon

Answer (score 1):

If the `.ico` file does not contain the 256x256 full size PNG icon, Windows seems to be happy when I simply write:

```
var assembly = typeof (Xyz).Assembly;
var stream   = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream ("Foo.Resources.Form.ico");
var icon     = new System.Drawing.Icon (stream);

form.Icon = icon;
```

With that in place, and an icon named `Form.ico` placed in a `Resources` folder of my assembly, which has `Foo` as its default namespace, Windows will be using the 32x32 version of the image for the taskbar and task switching with Alt-Tab, and the 16x16 version for the title of the window.

So, beware of the PNG icon when using it with WinForms' `Form.Icon`...

Answer (score 0):

This problem seem to be fixed in modern versions of Visual Studio / Windows. If I load via `LoadIcon` and set both small and normal icon in window class with the same multi-size .ico file, Shell seems to be able to figure this out and load appropriate icon in Alt-Tab / Taskbar / Titlebar / Small / Medium / Big and even Giant icons in Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

**HICON** is a single sized icon, but it can also contain source information  where it was loaded from. It must have such info so **DrawIconEx** call (in titlebar/taskbar/alt-tab dialog) may choose better fit icon instead of resizing. You can check that by a call to **GetIconInfoEx**.

Just quoting Raymond Chen:

If you create an icon by calling **LoadIcon**, the window manager loads the specified icon from the module you specified, but it also remembers where the icon came from. (This discussion also applies, mutatis mutandis to cursors, but I will just talk about icons to avoid awkardness.) When you pass the **LR_COPYFROMRESOURCE** flag to the **CopyImage** function, the window manager goes back to the original icon source to create the copy you requested rather than blindly stretching the pixels of the icon you passed in.

Remember that an ICO file represents not just one icon but rather a collection of icons (known as an “icon group”), each at a different size or color depth. The intent is that each icon in the icon group depicts the same underlying image, just tuned for particular settings. (Now, mind you, there is no enforcement of this intent. If you make your 16×16 image a smiling-face and your 32×32 image a barking dog, well, then that’s your problem.) For example, a single ICO file might contain a 16×16 image, a 32×32 image, and a 48×48 image. If somebody asks for the icon at one of those sizes, then the corresponding image is used. On the other hand, if somebody asks for, say, the 24×24 image, the window manager will take the 32×32 image and stretch it to the necessary size.

You can recover this “hidden source information” with the **GetIconInfoEx** function (new for Windows Vista). If the icon was loaded by ordinal, then the **szResName** is an empty string and the ordinal is placed in the **wResID** member. If the icon was loaded by name, then **wResID** is zero and **szResName** contains the resource name.

We’ve seen that icons and cursors know where they came from, and the window manager uses this information when you ask it to change the size of an icon. But not all icons carry this information, only icons created by passing a **HINSTANCE** and a resource name.

You can use this to your advantage if you want to destroy the module and resource information associated with an icon. For example, the **CreateIconIndirect** function creates an icon from raw bitmap information without reference to an **HINSTANCE** or a resource name. This allows you to create icons at runtime, but it also allows you to create an icon that “throws away” the bonus information.

```
HICON CopyIconWithoutResourceInfo(HICON hicoSrc)
{
  ICONINFO ii;
  HICON hico = NULL;
  if (GetIconInfo(hicoSrc, &ii)) {
    hico = CreateIconIndirect(&ii);
    if (ii.hbmMask) DeleteObject(ii.hbmMask);
    if (ii.hbmColor) DeleteObject(ii.hbmColor);
  }
  return hico;
}
```

Now, throwing away this information is a desperation move, because it prevents the window manager from using the original resource information when resizing an icon, resulting in ugly stretched icons.

You might even be throwing this information away by mistake. For example, if your program is asked to produce an icon, it’s best if you load the icon with a function like LoadImage because that records the bonus information; if the caller decides to resize the icon, it can do so with the CopyImage function while retaining full fidelity. On the other hand, if you use a function like **ExtractIcon** or **CreateIconFromResource**, that will not have the bonus information, and any icon stretching that takes place will end up looking pretty ugly.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080820-00/?p=21173
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080822-00/?p=21133