# SetClassLong(hWnd, GCL_HICON, hIcon) cannot replace WinForms Form.Icon

Tags: winforms, winapi, pinvoke, icons

I'd like to use a specific `ICO` file as my icon with a WinForms application. Since I want to be able to specify a small icon (16x16) for the title bar and a normal icon (32x32) when Alt-Tabbing, I cannot use the `Form.Icon` property which accepts a single `System.Drawing.Icon` object, which forces me to use either the low res icon, or the normal icon.

I posted a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2234988/how-to-set-hicon-on-a-window-ico-with-multiple-sizes) which came up with a very simple solution which works fine for native Win32 applications:

```
SetClassLong(hWnd, GCL_HICON, hIcon32x32);
SetClassLong(hWnd, GCL_HICONSM, hIcon16x16);
```

Trying to apply the same trick on a `Form` does not work. I have following P/Invoke definitions:

```
[DllImport ("User32.dll")]
extern static int SetClassLong(System.IntPtr hWnd, int index, int value);

const int GCL_HICON   = -14;
const int GCL_HICONSM = -34;
```

and I then simply call:

```
System.IntPtr hIcon32x32 = ...;
System.IntPtr hIcon16x16 = ...;
SetClassLong(this.Handle, GCL_HICON, hIcon32x32.ToInt32());
SetClassLong(this.Handle, GCL_HICONSM, hIcon16x16.ToInt32());
```

and never call `Form.Icon`. This does not work, however:

1. The icon in the form is still the default WinForms provided icon.
2. When pressing Alt-Tab, I still see the WinForms default icon.

...but, what's interesting, is that when I press Alt-Tab, I see for a very very short moment the icon I defined using `GCL_HICON` (or `GCL_HICONSM` if I do not use `GCL_HICON`). Something seems to be happening behind the scenes, which forces Windows to paint the icon using the WinForms default icon.

I can't figure out what I've done wrong and what is going on behind the scenes.

edited: I really want to be able to provide two different icons created on the fly, not bind the `Form.Icon` to an icon on disk. That's why I am trying to use the P/Invoke code to specify the icons in memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't actually verified this by testing it or looking at the disassembled WinForms code, so I'm not sure if this answer will satisfy the bounty condition of "credible and/or official sources". But I think I'm pretty [in]credible, so I'll give it a shot anyway!

You're setting the icon associated with the window *class*. You're doing it with the `SetClassLong[Ptr]` function and `GCL_HICON`/`GCL_HICONSM` indices, but it has the same effect as setting it in the [`WNDCLASSEX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633577.aspx) structure at the time that the class is registered. This sets the *default* icon for windows of that class.

However, individual windows can set their own icons, overriding the default icon provided by their class. You do this by sending the `WM_SETICON` message, passing either `ICON_BIG` or `ICON_SMALL` as the `wParam` and a handle to the icon as the `lParam`. Presumably, this is what WinForms is doing. That's why the "default" WinForms icon is appearing instead of the default window class icon you're assigning, because WinForms is setting its default icon using `WM_SETICON`, not via the window class. The only thing "default" about the WinForms icon is that it's assigned automatically by the framework if you don't assign a different custom icon. It doesn't fit any other definition of "default"—certainly not one that might be used from a Win32 perspective.

The `Form.Icon` property definitely uses `WM_SETICON` to modify the icon, that's why it is working as expected. Now, you say you don't want to set the Icon property because

> I really want to be able to provide two different icons created on the fly, not bind the Form.Icon to an icon on disk. That's why I am trying to use the P/Invoke code to specify the icons in memory.

But that doesn't mean you can't set the `Icon` property. You can specify a handle to an icon (`HICON`) here, just as well as you can if you use P/Invoke. All you need is the static [`Icon.FromHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.icon.fromhandle.aspx) method, which creates a new `Icon` object from the specified `HICON`. You then assign this `Icon` object to the form's `Icon` property.

You don't have to, though. You can use P/Invoke if you want:

```
const int WM_SETICON = 0x80;

enum IconType
{
    ICON_BIG   = 1;
    ICON_SMALL = 0;
}

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd,
                                 int message,
                                 IntPtr wParam,
                                 IntPtr lParam);
```

Then, call it similar to what you have:

```
IntPtr hIcon32x32 = ...;
IntPtr hIcon16x16 = ...;
SendMessage(this.Handle, WM_SETICON, (IntPtr)IconType.ICON_BIG, hIcon32x32);
SendMessage(this.Handle, WM_SETICON, (IntPtr)IconType.ICON_SMALL, hIcon16x16);
```

Only one thing you're doing wrong: assuming that the "big" icon will always be 32x32 pixels and that the "small" icon will always be 16x16 pixels. At least, I'm assuming that you're doing this from the names of the variables. If so, that's an invalid assumption. Those are only the most common sizes. They are not guaranteed to be the same in all environments. This is why it's important to provide larger icons in your .ico file; for example, a 48x48 icon. Since you're setting the icons dynamically, Windows won't have access to a larger icon to downsample and you might end up with something really blurry and ugly when your 32x32 icon is scaled up.

To retrieve the *actual* sizes, call the `GetSystemMetrics` function. The `SM_CXICON` and `SM_CYICON` flags will tell you the X and Y dimensions, respectively, of the "big" icon. The `SM_CXSMICON` and `SM_CYSMICON` flags will tell you the X and Y dimensions, respectively, of the "small" icon.

```
const int SM_CXICON   = 11;
const int SM_CYICON   = 12;
const int SM_CXSMICON = 49;
const int SM_CYSMICON = 50;

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern int GetSystemMetrics(int smIndex);
```

```
static Size GetBigIconSize()
{
    int x = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXICON);
    int y = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYICON);
    return Size(x, y);
}
static Size GetSmallIconSize()
{
    int x = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSMICON);
    int y = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSMICON);
    return Size(x, y);
}
```

Comment: This did the trick, combined with the fact that I have to show the form before applying the icon changes. Thank you very much for all the time you put into your answer and for the detailed explanation.

Comment: @Pierre Indeed, that's because WinForms overrides the class default icon with its own "default" icon when the form is created. But that only happens if the form's `Icon` property is `null`. I've shown you that you can assign an `HICON` value to that property, and you can do this before the form gets shown. The framework should then initialize the form with the proper icon automatically. The logic is in the getter for the `Icon` property. If there is no user icon set and the form is not a restricted window, it returns the result of `Form.DefaultIcon`, an internal static method.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Form.Icon`. You just need a single icon file that contains 16x16 and 32x32 pixel versions of your icon.

I just tried it, using a single icon file that contains a 32x32 pixel red circle and a 16x16 blue rectangle. The small windows icon shows the blue rectangle, the alt-tab icon shows a red circle.

No need for P/Invoke at all.

Comment: Thank you for your answer; I was not aware of that. But ...

In my case, I don't want to use an icon file as the source for `Form.Icon` because I want to be able to generate the small and large icons on the fly. And the magic behind `Form.Icon` of loading small and large icon versions won't work, as I have no idea how to create a single `HICON` which would contain both sizes.